# Script to search folders for OCR's PDFs

Tags: bash, shell, pdf

I've written a script to search through one folder to let me know what PDF has fonts (quick way to know if it's been OCR'd unless anyone knows of a better one)

What I can't do on my script is for it to search through all the folders within the main DIR?

Any thoughts?

```
!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
PDFDIR=/home/user/Temp/Docs/*.pdf
for f in $PDFDIR
do
echo "******************PDF***********************"
pdffonts $f
echo "$f"
echo "******************PDf***********************"
done > output.txt
# restore $IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
PDFDIR=/home/user/Temp/Docs/*.pdf
for f in $PDFDIR
```

to this:

```
PDFDIR=/home/user/Temp/Docs
for f in $(find $PDFDIR -type f -name "*.pdf")
```

Comment: Iterating over find output in a for loop will break if any of his files contain spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You'd do better to use `find`:

```
find /home/usr/Temp/Docs -name \*.pdf -exec echo "***PDF***" -print -exec pdffonts {} \; -exec echo "***END PDF***" \;
```